# Implementing undo function using redux-undo

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to make "undo & Redo" with redux-toolkit & redux-undo

but, redux-undo is not working in my code.

How can I make "undo & Redo"  function with redux toolkit?

and Could it be a version issue?

"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
"redux-undo": "^1.0.1",

I tried to change @reduxjs/toolkit version -> 1.2.5
and then it is not working

lastly I tried to change redux from redux-toolkit
is it okay?

if not? is it any solution?

```
**import { ActionCreators } from "redux-undo";**

...
...
const handleUndo = () => {
    **dispatch(ActionCreators.undo());**
  };

const handleRedo = () => {
    **dispatch(ActionCreators.redo());**
  };
```

### creatSlice.js

```
/* eslint-disable*/
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


//* 드래그 시작된 항목 변경
let config = createSlice({
  name: "config",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addConfig(state, action) {
      if (action.payload === "Button") {
        let newElement = {
          id: Date.now(),
          component: action.payload,
          props: {
            text: "Button",
            message: "",
          },
        };
        return [...state, newElement];
      }
      if (action.payload === "Paragraph") {
        let newElement = {
          id: Date.now(),
          component: action.payload,
          props: {
            text: "Paragraph",
          },
        };
        return [...state, newElement];
      }
    },
    editParagraphConfig(state, action) {
      state[action.payload.id].props.text = action.payload.target;
    },
    editButtonConfig(state, action) {
      state[action.payload.id].props.text = action.payload.target;
    },
    editButtonMSGConfig(state, action) {
      state[action.payload.id].props.message = action.payload.target;
    },
    addImportConfig(state, action) {
      return [...action.payload];
    },
  },
});

export let {
  addConfig,
  editParagraphConfig,
  editButtonConfig,
  editButtonMSGConfig,
  addImportConfig,
} = config.actions;

export default config;
```

Comment: Is there some type of error you are experiencing or can you give any more information?

Comment: I would say that you forgot to use undoable reducer in your createSlice